# 'Device not ready' to D-Link DFE-580TX Wired Network Adapters

Tags: 12.04

My 3 Quad port network adapters can be recognised when I write the 'ifconfig' command, but they all seem to be in 'Device not ready' state when I click on the networking tab at the toolbar (please see pictures below).

At the 'System Setting' they all seem to be recognised but again, their state doesn't change when I plug a network cable into them.

Could anybody advise if there is a solution to this problem? I'm a new Linux user (Have been using it for the past month).

The network adapters I have are the D-Link DFE-580TX.

The adapters used to work excellent with 11.10, but since I switched to 12.04 (32bit or 64bit) they stopped working.

From the Toolbar menu, it says that it's a 'Wired Network (D-Link DL 10050 Sundance Ethernet).

Thank you all.

```
user@Phoenix:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:5f:f4:2b:f9:bb  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:45 Base address:0xa000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0d:88:70:da:38  
          inet6 addr: fe80::20d:88ff:fe70:da38/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:32
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:8666 (8.6 KB)
          Interrupt:16 Base address:0xc180 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0d:88:70:da:39  
          inet6 addr: fe80::20d:88ff:fe70:da39/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:27
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:7650 (7.6 KB)
          Interrupt:17 Base address:0xc100 

eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0d:88:70:da:3a  
          inet6 addr: fe80::20d:88ff:fe70:da3a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:34
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:9078 (9.0 KB)
          Interrupt:18 Base address:0xc080 

eth4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0d:88:70:da:3b  
          inet6 addr: fe80::20d:88ff:fe70:da3b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:36
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:10074 (10.0 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0xc000
```

And here is the 'lspci | grep Ethernet' output:

```
user@Phoenix:~$ 
user@Phoenix:~$ lspci | grep Ethernet
04:04.0 Ethernet controller: D-Link System Inc DL10050 Sundance Ethernet (rev 14)
04:05.0 Ethernet controller: D-Link System Inc DL10050 Sundance Ethernet (rev 14)
04:06.0 Ethernet controller: D-Link System Inc DL10050 Sundance Ethernet (rev 14)
04:07.0 Ethernet controller: D-Link System Inc DL10050 Sundance Ethernet (rev 14)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't help much, But I had a similar issue when setting up a friend's Ubuntu box with a Broadcom Wireless PCI card in it. If I remember right, the device (at least for my specific case) required a firmware .bin file in addition to the built-in driver. If this is the case, these firmware files cannot be distributed with Ubuntu because they are proprietary software, and card specific. That's as much help as I can be.

Comment: Any network drivers guru here please?

Comment: I found a temporary solution for this. Killing the NetworkManager app itself, it will start automatically, and everything is identified.

Answer (score 0):

```
killall -9 NetworkManager
```

Use this command. It kills all processes on network card and restart it. I use it each and every time I use Ubunutu.